# impact to AUC if swap positive and negative during model training

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, roc, auc

If I swap positive class and negative class, then train a model again (I tried decision tree, adaboost, svm from scikit-learn built-in package) for a two class classification problem. Sometimes, I can see AUC slightly change (around 1-2%). Anyone have any ideas why there are such changes?

For ROC curve, x-axis is false positive rate, and y-axis and true positive rate. When prediction model gives prediction scores, we will order the scores from higher value to lower value, and then choose threshold according to the sorted values and calculate at the specific threshold point, what is the fpr and tpr. AUC is the area under ROC.

BTW, for swap, I mean manually assign negative label to be 1 and manually assign positive label as 0. I am asking if I swap, whether area of AUC may change?

**Edit 1**, here is how adaboost works, confused why it is not converged? From the formula, it should be converged. Refer from this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This should have no effect on anything whatsoever.  Your model is now predicting the "zero" class instead of the "one" class, which is just a matter of what names we're using for things.

Comment: @dsaxton, but I observer something 1-2% differences, let me try to post some data. BTW, for your comment, "This should have no effect on anything whatsoever", I think you mean AUC should be the same no matter we swap 0 or 1? Thanks.

Comment: Is there some randomness involved in the model fitting procedure?  That could explain it, otherwise there should be no difference.  That's because by flipping the labels the model is solving the exact same problem as before, which is classifying things into one of two classes.  All that's changed is what we're calling an event and how we should interpret the model scores.

Comment: @dsaxton, thanks. What do you mean randomness? You mean for example, I random select training/testing to be 5:5, so that each time training/testing are not exactly the same (when I flip positive/negative class label)? Or you mean something else?

Comment: Yes. Random forests for instance use random sampling of the data / predictors, so fitting the model twice will result in slightly different models.

Comment: @dsaxton, how about adaboost?

Comment: adaboost is not convergent, it random walks around in a small region of the solution space.

Comment: Thanks @Carl, so how your answer related to my original question? :)

Comment: Well, random noise. That is adaboost never settles down, it takes a walk in solution space, if you restart with new initial conditions, it will not wind up in exactly the same place as the last time around.

Comment: To answer that it would help me if you explained AUC of what curve, and details like that to help clarify the question.

Comment: @Carl, I have add comments to explain ROC. If there are anything unclear, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Still unclear. The average reader likely knew what ROC was. It would have been enough to say AUC(ROC). What is missing here in "impact to AUC if swap positive and negative during model training" is 1) sense 2) grammar, 3) punctuation. Consider "What is the impact on AUC of ROC of training path of models, e.g., when positive and negative classes are swapped during model training?" Next, +/- classes of WHAT? Next, decision tree, adaboost, AND svm from scikit-learn built-in package IN WHAT SOFTWARE? You included no computer language tag.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Carl, and vote up. Wondering if the unclear point iw what means "swap“ I mentioned here? If so, I can clarify what means swap.

Comment: Did you set an initial seed for the model? May be that can remove any  randomness in the model you are using.

Comment: @DileepKumarPatchigolla, thanks and vote up. What do you mean initial seed? In my case, training and testing are fixed.

Comment: Here is another question about setting seed. It speaks about R, but conceptually it's the same for Python as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605271/reasons-for-using-the-set-seed-function
However seeing your comment to another answer below that re-running the model without swapping seems to give you the exact result, I suspect setting seed won't help.

Comment: Thanks @DileepKumarPatchigolla, vote up for your reply and reference. Wondering if training and testing data are exact the same, do you think any possible AUC will change if we swap positive and negative label? Suppose we can use any models? My thought is algorithm like random forest may still give different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one can show that the algorithms are not convergent. They get to close to a solution and then do a [random walk](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.84.8128).

Comment: Thanks Carl, but it cannot explain, if I do not swap positive and native label, AUC never changed. If there are randomness in adaboost Sci-kit learn implementation, even if I do not swap positive/negative label, result of AUC should also diff each time I run, correct?

Comment: Well, if the same randomization (or its equivalent as inflexible algorithmic choice) is being repeated each time, then the runs will be identical, not correct, just identical. If one chooses different start conditions, then even the same randomization will lead to different answers.

Comment: Thanks Carl, vote up for your reply. I think adaboost should be converged. I post how it works in my original post, maybe it is specific implementation issue it is not converged? Could you help to summarize why it is not converged?

Comment: BTW, Carl, the purpose I post adaboost process is want to show there is no kinds of randomness in the process, so not sure why it is not converged (as long as training data is fixed, initial weight is fixed and number of weak classifier is fixed).

Comment: And if the training interval is extended, what then? There is nothing sacrosanct about the training interval.

Comment: What do you mean training interval? Do you mean how many weaker classifiers?

Comment: @LinMa The training interval looks like $1$ to $M$ in your equations. Increase $M$ and watch what happens.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Carl, mark your reply as answer and grant bounty points.

Answer (score 3):

I reproduced this so we can use my notebook as a reference:

https://github.com/csizsek/crossvalidated/blob/03ea088e0805bf550750d27735b38ebe1c9b567a/changing_roc_auc_score.ipynb

The data set I used is a simple Ecoli classification data set. You can see that I run the same classificator two times with the label unchanged, then I swap the labels and run it twice again and the ROC AUC score is always slightly different.

The reason why this is happening is exactly what @dsaxton said: that most classification algorithms (in this case a Random Forest) use some kind of random bootstrapping or something else that is random and the result model is always slightly different thus it's predictions and the ROC AUC score is different as well.

Comment: Thanks Peter, nice advice and vote up. Wondering if training and testing data are fixed, if there are still some randomness possible?

Comment: BTW, Peter, but it cannot explain, if I do not swap positive and native label, AUC never changed. If there are randomness in random forest Sci-kit learn implementation, even if I do not swap positive/negative label, result of AUC should also diff each time I run, correct?

Comment: 1) There is randomness in _random_ forests, [wiki Random Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest#From_bagging_to_random_forests).
2) Scikit-learn's implementation of random forest without random_state parameter gives me slightly different result each time. [modified notebook from the answer](https://github.com/m212121/crossvalidated/blob/master/changing_roc_auc_score.ipynb)
3) If you can share data and/or implementation it would be better.